# How to hide specific iframe elements from JAWS frames list?

Tags: html, iframe, accessibility

I've got some specific iframe elements that I want to be able to hide from the JAWS frame list (insert + f9). There are other iframes that are very important so just having [a user ignore iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454936/2675087) isn't going to work.

Is it possible to do this?

Edit: I should mention why. There is a user option that changes whether specific types of windows open in a new window or open in an iframe on the page, even if the option is set to open in a new window the iframe is still there but the src is set to a blank html file. In that case I(or if it's set to load in the iframe but it isn't at the moment) the content of the iframe is useless to the user and I'd rather hide it from them. I'd rather not make major changes to the code if I can avoid it.

Comment: Do you want the user to choose to ignore, or are you making the decision for the user?

Comment: @RyanB I edited my post with some clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I found a post here earlier, but can't now; however, read: http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/11/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-aria-hidden-support/

Comment: i'm sure this is client request, but what's the background here? since when is it ok to tell the user whats good for them? not picking at you, just curious...

Comment: @albert My company is making a big push for 508 compliance so we have to make our stuff accessible. I want to hide this iframe because it is of no use to them. The iframe/new window opens allowing the user to enter some data related to what they're doing at the moment, if the user has settings set to open up in a new window the iframe is never going to be used, otherwise the iframe would only be used when selecting data. The iframe is never visible unless it's being used to enter data, so invisible to sighted users, and I don't want blind users thinking they can enter info when they can't.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide it with CSS (`visibility: hidden` or `display: none`) or with `aria-hidden="true"`.

Comment: Might be specific to the JAWS version you're testing; works fine for me with JAWS 15 / IE11.  If these don't work, there's really nothing else you can do, other than only insert the iframes when they are needed.

Comment: Ahh,  I'm using JAWS 14, IE 10.